# TypeORM: using the CASE expression in find options

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

Is there any way of using the CASE expression in TypeORM's find options? I know you can use it on the QueryBuilder (covered [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3167)).

```
connection.getRepository(Customer).createQueryBuilder("customer")
            .select(["customer.CustomerName", "customer.City", "customer.Country"])
            .orderBy("(CASE WHEN customer.City IS NULL THEN customer.Country ELSE customer.City END)")
            .getMany();
```

But is there a similar way of doing a customized sorting based on two columns using the find options?

I tried reading the documentation but could not find anything about CASE expressions.